# AWS Sig v4 Signing for API Gateway

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

Is there some way to lookup the region of an apigateway endpoint and use that to sign your requests with sigv4?

I'm using the aws sdk to do the signing like so

```
let req    = new AWS.HttpRequest( endpoint );
req.method = 'POST';
req.path   = endpoint.path;
req.region = QueryApi.getBaseUrlRegion( this._baseUrl );
req.body   = JSON.stringify( body );

req.headers[ 'Host' ]              = endpoint.host
req.headers[ 'presigned-expires' ] = false
req.headers[ 'Content-Type' ]      = 'application/json'

let signer = new AWS.Signers.V4( req, 'execute-api' )
signer.addAuthorization( this._awsCreds, new Date() )
```

Right now I am parsing the region from the internal aws execute-api url, but this won't work with a custom dns name.

Are the only options using a config, or doing a DNS lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently there isn't a way to look up the region when using a custom domain name. Using DNS lookup will not work as well because API Gateway is fronted by CloudFront distributions.